# How to create a table by using the variables of a column from a dataset in R?

Tags: r, data-science

I have a `data.frame` which is like :

```
data.frame("Hhold Id" = c(173,174,174,175,176,176,176), "Individuals" = c(1,1,2,1,1,2,3))
```

Individuals indicate the nth individuals for that household. Namely, for example Hhold 173 includes one individual while Hhold 176 composed by three individuals. I would like to get a new table which indicates how many individuals exist for each household without duplicating the Hhold Id. Such as :

```
data.frame("Hhold Id" = c(173,174,175,176), "Individuals" = c(1,2,1,3))
```

I have tried `unique` and `group by` functions, but could not get a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `as.data.frame(table(df$Hhold.Id))`?

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table library

```
data.table(data)[,list(Individuals=max(Individuals)),list("Hhold Id"=Hhold.Id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("Hhold Id" = c(173,174,174,175,176,176,176), "Individuals" =  
   c(1,1,2,1,1,2,3))

df_summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Hhold.Id) %>%
  summarise(Individuals = max(Individuals))
```

Comment: You might consider adding some more context to your answer, instead of a code-only answer. This helps everyone get better from your answer. You can read how to create better answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer